# SocketServer and Socket Communication, Answer Not received

Tags: java, sockets

I have made a java ServerSocket. I send a request to it using a Socket Object. The request is delivered to the ServerSocket but the response does not come back.

Server Code :

```
                Socket startserver = this.wifiserver.accept();

                in = new InputStreamReader(startserver.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(in);
                String request = read.readLine();
                //System.out.println(request);

                if(request.equals("SNDKEY")){
                    System.out.println("Command is: SNDKEY");
                    out = new PrintWriter(startserver.getOutputStream());
                    out.print("12345678901234567890");
                    out.close();

                }
```

Client Code:

```
        Socket connection = new Socket( ip, port );
        writeServer = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        inputStream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
        bufferStream = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        writeServer.print("SNDKEY");


        this.Key = bufferStream.readLine();
```

The problem is that the program gets stuck at the command bufferStream.readLine(). I have checked that the request is reaching the server by outputing the line command is: SNDKEY and it always gets printing out. But the key is never received at the user end.

Comment: Try printing a newline in your client code or call `flush()` to flush the outputstream so that the server can see some data.

Comment: Can you change `out.print(...)` to `out.println(...)`?

Comment: @Vikdor Can you please explain. What do you mean by server can see some data?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Still the same problem. The bufferStream.readLine() blocks the program.

Comment: The buffer to which the client writes doesn't get flushed until a newline is encountered or the buffer's capacity is full or a flush() is called explicitly. Until the content is not flushed from the client side, the server will not see that data in its buffered reader.

Comment: @Vikdor: flushing the buffer solved the issue, after the println was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufferStream.readLine()` blocks until a newline is received. But on the server side you are outputting with `PrintWriter.print()`, which doesn't send any newlines unless you tell it to. So the client waits forever. Either change the print to println, or add a newline character to the end of the message:

```
out.print("12345678901234567890\n");
```

When you don't want to use newlines in your protocol, you could alternatively use `bufferStream.read` instead of `bufferStream.readLine` to return after reading each byte or after reading a specific number of bytes.